# Visual Basic Reading specific Lines

Tags: vb.net, loading, streamreader

I have the visual basic code saving correctly but I need it to load a specific line and set it to an integer, here is the code I have for saving

```
 Dim Red as Integer
    Dim b as String
    b = ""
            Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(Path)
            Do While objReader.Peek() >= -1
                b = File.ReadLines(Path).Skip(1).Take(1).First()

            Loop
            objReader.Close()
    val(b)
            Red = b
            TextBox2.Text = Red
```

When I use this, it freezes up and I have to close it using task manager, is there another way to format this so it works properly?

Comment: Is that VBA?
 Looks more like VB.NET

Comment: I'm going to roll back your edit. If you want to post a solution to the problem for people in the future to see, post an actual answer in the space below that is provided for that purpose. It's acceptable to answer your own question here - see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/self-answer) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I found that by removing the do loop that the code will read that specific line as needed without crashing the system with skip being the number of lines it skips.

```
Dim Red as Integer
    Dim b as String
    b = ""
            Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(Path)
                b = File.ReadLines(Path).Skip(1).Take(1).First()
            objReader.Close()
    val(b)
            Red = b
            TextBox2.Text = Red
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    dim myfilepath as string = "c:\myfilepath"
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(myfilepath) Then
    dim mytext s string() = split(My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(myfilepath),vbCrLf)
    dim red as integer 
    dim  linecounter as integer = 0
    dim specificline as integer = "e.g." 0
    For linecounter 0 to ubound(mytext)
    if linecounter = specifline
    red = mytext(x)
    end if
    next

    end if
```